# Django TruncMinute show timezone

Tags: django, django-queryset, truncate, timestamp-with-timezone

I created a Django ORM query and I use `TruncMinute` to set seconds to zeros. Unfortunately when I run my query the result show my timezone.  I attached my result with my query and I also show my desired output.

**My query:**

```
MyResul=MyTable.objects.all()
        .filter(time__range=(start_date, end_date))
        .annotate(time_stamp=TruncMinute('time'))
        .values('data', 'time_stamp')
```

**My result:**

```
  data            time_stamp
   1     2017-01-04 18:56:00+00:00
```

**My attempt:**

```
   .annotate(time_stamp=TruncMinute('time', tzinfo=None))
```

**My desired output:**

```
 data            time_stamp
       1     2017-01-04 18:56:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you defined `time` field in your DB as `DateTimeField()`. Hence your result of the query will be as,

```
<QuerySet [{'data': 1, 'time_stamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 24, 13, 36, 21, 942863, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]><br>
```

That is `time_stamp` key holds a value that is belongs to python's `datetime` object. So if you are trying to show the data anywhere (HTML,Json etc), you have to format it (If I'm not wrong,).
So my answer is, iterate the `MyResul` and `format` the `datetime` object

```
temp_result = MyTable.objects.filter(time__range=(start_date, end_date)).values('data', 'time')
MyResul = []
for result in temp_result:
    MyResul.append({
        "data": result['data'],
        "time_stamp": result['time'].strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:00')
    })
#use 'MyResul'
```